# An image call in javascript and css files in liferay 6.2

Tags: javascript, css, jakarta-ee, liferay, liferay-6

I'm working with liferay 6.2. In /js/myJSFile.js. and /css/myCSSFile I want to make a call to images existing in /img folder.
Exemple of css file:

```
background: white url(list.gif) no-repeat left center;
```

Example of javascript file:

```
ddtreemenu.closefolder="closed.gif"
```

please help.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is not in the same folder as your js file, you'll have to navigate to the image folder to retrieve the image.

From what you say, your folder structure looks something like this:

```
/root/ 
   /js/myJSFile.js
    /css/myCSSFile.css
    /img/closed.gif
```

You can access your `closed.gif` image using a relative link like so:

`ddtreemenu.closefolder="../img/closed.gif"`

The `../` tells it to exit the current folder, `/js/`, and then it can navigate to the `closed.gif` file the rest of the way.

Comment: actualy in liferay we can't access files easly as you said. we use in jsp files for instance: <%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/closed.gif . is there a manner like that tu use in javascript and css files files

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue; The example above will work in both CSS and JavaScript to retrieve the image from the `/img/` folder. Are you asking about retrieving the absolute path to that file or just accessing the image from a .js file in another folder?

Comment: yeah, I'm asking about retrieving the absolute path.

Comment: No, you can't use CSS or JavasScript to get an absolute path to a file. That is something that needs to be handled by your back-end.

Comment: yep, I know that. and I was asking for a manner to acheive my goal. I think my question was clear!!!

Answer (score -1):

You should use Liferay preDefine Velocity variable for the access of images folder.

For example:

```
<img src="$images_folder/menu-icon.png" alt="Menu icon" title="Menu" />
```

in this code  `"$images_folder"` is preDefine Velocity variable, so in this way, you access images folder.